# In a compact metric space, every pair of homeomorphic open subsets has isomorphic basis?

Tags: general-topology, lattice-orders

Let X be a compact metric space, V and W be open subsets. Suppose there is an homemorphism from V to W. Let B be a countable basis for X and B(V), B(W) the relativized basis for V and W, respectively. Are B(V) and B(W) order isomorphic (under subset order)?
For instance, for X the unit interval, and B the usual basis of intervals with rational endpoints,
The problem  is that an homeomorphism between V and W does not need to send a basic open set into a basic open set. I do not know how to define an order isomorphism between B(V) and B(W).

Comment: For the unit interval, it seems the answer is affirmative for the usual basis of intervals with rationals end point. We can  build the order isomorphism between the basis using  the fact that every two countable dense subsets of [0,1] (without end points) are order isomorphic.

Comment: If X is totally disconnected, the answer is possitive for the basis of clopen subsets.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general: for instance, $B(V)$ and $B(W)$ do not even have to have the same cardinality.  For a really simple example, consider $X=\{0,1,2\}$, $V=\{0,1\}$, $W=\{1,2\}$, and the basis $B$ that contains all the singletons as well as $\{0,1\}$.  Then $B(V)$ has three elements but $B(W)$ has only the two singletons.

More generally, $B$ might contain $V$ (or a superset of $V$) but not contain any superset of $W$, and then $B(V)$ will have a greatest element but $B(W)$ will not.

Comment: The question is for non discrete compact metric spaces.